# Iterate over list of tuples and create dictionary based on condition

Tags: python, tuples

Assuming I have a list of tuples like this:

```
t = [('one', 2), ('one', 4), ('one',9), ('two', 3), ('two', 5), ('two', 7), ('one', 11), ('one', 13), ('one', 14), ('one', 17), ('one', 19)]
```

how can I get the next output:

```
out = [{'no':'one', 'first':2, 'last':9},
      {'no':'two', 'first':3, 'last':7},
      {'no':'one', 'first':11, 'last':19}]
```

The overall condition is:
for each group of equal first elements keep only values of first and last elem in group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Walrus operator (Python 3.8+) to simplify kaya3 answer to work even with only one consecutive element

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[{'no':k, 
  'first': (p:=list(v))[0][1], 
  'last':   p[-1][1]} 
  for k, v in groupby(t, itemgetter(0))]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and unpacking:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

out = [
    {'no': k, 'first': a, 'last': b}
    for k, ((_, a), *_, (_, b)) in groupby(t, key=itemgetter(0))
]
```

The above will fail if you have any groups with just one consecutive element; to make it work in that case, you can do this:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def handle_group(k, v):
    _, first = next(v)
    try:
        *_, (_, last) = v
    except ValueError:
        last = first
    return {'no': k, 'first': first, 'last': last}

out = [
    handle_group(k, v)
    for k, v in groupby(t, key=itemgetter(0))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to write it without importing any module, here is an algorithm:

```
t = [('one', 2), ('one', 4), ('one', 9), ('two', 3), ('two', 5), ('two', 7),
     ('one', 11), ('one', 13), ('one', 14), ('one', 17), ('one', 19)]

res = [{'no': t[0][0], 'first': t[0][1], 'last': t[0][1]}]

for item in t[1:]:
    last_item_res = res[-1]
    if last_item_res['no'] == item[0]:

        if item[1] < last_item_res['first']:
            last_item_res['first'] = item[1]

        elif item[1] > last_item_res['last']:
            last_item_res['last'] = item[1]
    else:
        res.append({'no': item[0], 'first': item[1], 'last': item[1]})

for i in res:
    print(i)
```

I put the first item in the list, then I start comparing the min and the max values of the next items.